# How can I get access to IBM Q 20 Tokyo and IBM Q 20 Austin?

Tags: ibm-q-experience

How can I get access to IBM Q 20 Tokyo and IBM Q 20 Austin?

In the Q- experience site there is written that the access is for IBM clients only and in the profile there is a "promotional code" that you need to put to gain access to those chips.

How I became a IBM Q client and get this promotional code?

Answer (score 3):

The kinds of people that use these devices are affiliated with companies, quantum startups, or the IBMQ Hubs (in Oxford, Keio, Melbourne, ... ). The process is more involved than a simple web sign-up.

If you are a company and want to get the process started, you can use [this web form](https://www.research.ibm.com/ibm-q/network/), or try to ping someone important on the [Qiskit Slack](https://join.slack.com/t/qiskit/shared_invite/enQtNDc2NjUzMjE4Mzc0LTMwZmE0YTM4ZThiNGJmODkzN2Y2NTNlMDIwYWNjYzA2ZmM1YTRlZGQ3OGM0NjcwMjZkZGE0MTA4MGQ1ZTVmYzk).

If you are neither a company nor an academic at one of the hubs, then I'm afraid there is no scope for access to these devices. But there are, of course, the many publicly available devices that are just as awesome.

*Disclaimer: I work for IBM*

Answer (score 1):

By going to this [website](https://www.research.ibm.com/ibm-q/network/). 
But I do not know how exactly the process work.
It should involve your company/startup/institution and then you make some kind of agreement to be part of the "community".